# Calling a function in another class

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

I'm trying to call a function to another class after an event.

Here's my code:

From the doucment class:

```
public static function redrawMap():void {
            removeChild(global.world);
            var world:WorldHandler = new WorldHandler(40,30);
            global.world = world;
            addChild(global.world);
            world.mask = MapArea;
        }
```

From the class I'm calling from:

```
WorldDesign.clearButton.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, clearWorld);    
public function clearWorld(evt:MouseEvent):void{
                WorldDesign.redrawMap();
            }
```

I can't get it to work correctly, I get weird messages like "Call to undefined method removeChild" and it pointing to the redrawMap function. Which means it found the function, but I can't seem to do anything with it.

Any ideas?

Comment: `removeChild` is an instance method. You cannot call it from inside a static method.

Answer (score 0):

Since redrawMap is a static method, you also need to call removeChild and addChild like static methods:

```
public static function redrawMap():void {
    WorldDesign.removeChild(global.world);
    var world:WorldHandler = new WorldHandler(40,30);
    global.world = world;
    WorldDesign.addChild(global.world);
    world.mask = MapArea;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`redrawMap()` has been defined as a `static` method. This means it can not access any instance methods like `removeChild()`.

The solution would be to make it an instance method -- define it as `public function redrawMap()`. Then you can call the function through instances. That is, you'll have to instantiate the WorldDesign class somewhere (presumably during initialization of the rest of the swf)

```
var worldDesign:WorldDesign=new WorldDesign();
```

Then you can call redrawMap() as

```
worldDesign.redrawMap()
```

Answer (score 0):

Best way is don`t use static method at all. Use Singleton pattern for this.

```
class WorldDesign {
   private static var _instance:WorldDesign;
   public static function get instance():WorldDesign {
      if(!_instance) _instance = new WorldDesign();
      return _instance;
   }
   public function redrawMap():void {
      removeChild(global.world);
      var world:WorldHandler = new WorldHandler(40,30);
      global.world = world;
      addChild(global.world);
      world.mask = MapArea;
   }

}
```

And use WorldDesign.instance.redrawMap();